# C# .NET VS2013 Textbox (used for typing password) is not recognised by Password Manager)

Tags: c#

Program written in C# i VS2013 (Program "Login" on the screen). I have one edit box and one button. I use default system char for masking password in this textbox. This window is not recognisec as login window - I think because textbox is not recognised as Editbox for passsword. Unfortunetelly I cant add this window to Password Manader manually.

I write for test in VS 2013 in  c++ with wxWidgets app which is perfectly recognised. See screen attached where i analyse both of the programs in window detective. ONLY C++ wx program is recognised.

Is it possible to write sth in C# .NET to make Password Manager recognise window as login screen?

[a busy cat http://4programmers.net/store/forum/34650039354d1f9ae70a84.png](http://4programmers.net/store/forum/34650039354d1f9ae70a84.png)